# No scilab gui (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, scilab

I installed scilab in Ubuntu 12.04.  When I start in terminal or from KDE application menu, I only get a scilab console.  Why don't I get the gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some kind of X or QT problem.  I'm using XFCE, but it works in KDE.

Answer (score 0):

try install it,

```
apt-get install scilab
```

**scilab-cli** is just the console in a terminal.

Comment: It is installed.  That's how I know I'm getting the console and not the gui.